# Retrieving key,value pairs from memcached using Spymemcached

Tags: mapreduce, key-value, spymemcached

I store key,value pairs in memcached in which many values have the same key thus leading to identical pairs. Now, I want a combined list of values per key. I am not able to get this done. Can we possibly make a Hashmap in memcached? Or a list of key value pairs? refering which I can retrieve the values seperately?

Answer (score 0):

You can always store a list (comma separated etc.) for a key, and retrieve it, explode it.... For instance, php's serialize/unserialize() is a nice way to retrieve generic objects from memcache.